# Removing the numbers from bxSlider's pager

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I've tried using z-index: -1, color: transparent and visibility: hidden etc.. to remove the numbers from the bxSlider pager so that it just leaves the image dots. 'color: transparent' works for the text on every browser besides IE 7 and 8.

The CSS solutions out there for IE7 and IE8 don't seem to work at all.

Any help would be fantasic to either remove the numbers from the script itself or be able to use CSS to remove the text in IE7 and 8.

Thanks.

Comment: negative text-indent them off the page  `text-indent:-9999px`

Comment: Didn't fix the issue, sorry to say. :\

Comment: why not? Is a very common method and there is no reason for it not to work. You are either not targeting correct css selector, or not making selector specific enough

Comment: It's targeting the correct element. I went back to make sure by turning the text pink with using that again - once again, didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try `font-size:0;`
Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

@charlietfl is right but 'text-indent' will work only on block or float element.

Try this :

```
a{display:block; text-indent:-9999px} or

a{float:left; text-indent:-9999px}
```

Answer (score 1):

Text-indent doesn't works on pager in bxSlider. Try to add this code to your css:

```
.pager-link {color:transparent;}
```

this will hide the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This will build empty `<a>` tags:

```
$('#bxslider').bxSlider({
    buildPager: function(slideIndex) {
        return '';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default BxSlider CSS has the `text-indent` property set hide the text off the screen. If you're seeing slide numbers it could be that you've forgotten to include `bxslider.css` file.

Check the [BxSlider examples](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified) - none of them need any special formatting to hide the numbers and just show the dots.